# Lambda Expression - Parameter cannot be known?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I've this class declared:

```
public class SimpleArea<T> where T: Control
{
    private T control;

    public SimpleArea(T control)
    {
        this.control = control;
    }

}
```

And on my Main Program, i want to do something like this:

```
var SimpleAreaPanel = SimpleArea<Panel>(p => { p.Height= 150; })
```

The problem is that he can't define the type of "p" the intellisense shows "Parameter ???p"

How can i accomplish this instruction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constructor doesn't take a lambda - it takes a `T` instance, so a `Panel`. Either *give* it a `Panel`, or write a constucor that can take that expression - maybe an `Action<T>`.

Personally, I suspect you mean simply:

```
new Panel {Height = 150}
```

which is an *object initializer*, not a lambda - i.e.

```
var SimpleAreaPanel = new SimpleArea<Panel>(
    new Panel { Height= 150 });
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you don't need to use lambda at all.

```
var SimpleAreaPanel = new SimpleArea<Panel>(new Panel{Height = 150});
```

Answer (score 1):

Mb you need something like this:

```
class SimpleArea<T> where T : Control, new()
{
    public T control;

    public SimpleArea(Action<T> action)
    {
        control = new T();
        action(control);
    }
}
```

So you can write:

```
var SimpleAreaPanel = new SimpleArea<Panel>(p => { p.Height = 150; });
```

But I don't know what for...

Comment: @Marc, I see only one reason: it automatically creates instance of T.